# convert SQL data (with OR relationship) to redis data structure

Tags: redis, nosql

The data in SQL DB is:

[image: Id Key Values c1 1 Value 2 123 This is a row with only one cell This row is testing html entities]

We want to store this data in redis. But, the application will have "keys" and "values" data, and it want to fetch the corresponding "Id" from redis.

The "values" against any "key" are in OR relationship, but there is AND relationship between keys for any "Id" .
So, the application query to redis will be based on keys and values, and it wants to get the Id.

e.g. query from app : (K1 == V0 OR K1 == V1) AND (K2 == V2) ; then return c1 .

But, same key can be used by other Id .
e.g. (K1 == V2 OR K1 == V8) AND (K5 == V7) AND (K6 == V9 OR K1 == V8) ; should return c2 .

How do we store such data in Redis, to support these operations (without exponential growth)?

Comment: Hi @Prashant why you need this conversion?